# jquery: не работает выбор элемента по классу и атрибуту одновременно

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Пытаюсь выбрать все элементы, у которых есть класс `choosen` и атрибут `repeattype`. По отдельности работает, а оба условия сразу - нет:

```js
// все элементы с классом "choosen"
var allChoosen = $('.choosen');
console.log(allChoosen.length); // 1 элемент, как и ожидается

// все элементы с атрибутом "repeattype"
var allRepeattype = $('[repeattype]');
console.log(allRepeattype.length);  // 2 элемента, как и ожидается

// одновременно не получается:
var choosenAndRepeat = $('.choosen [repeattype]');
console.log(choosenAndRepeat.length); // 0 элементов почему-то

// пробовал поиск в выбранных (choosen)
// для наглядности сам элемент:
console.log(allChoosen[0]);
// значение атрибута достать можно:
console.log(allChoosen[0].getAttribute('repeattype'));
// но поиск в choosen по имени атрибута не работает:
console.log(allChoosen.find('[repeattype]').length);  // 0
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div repeattype="11111" class="choosen">1</div>
  <div repeattype="22222">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас пробел лишний

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас неправильно составлен селектор. `.choosen [repeattype]` означает элементы с атрибутом `repeattype`, являющиеся потомками элементов с классом `choosen`

Аналогично работает `allChoosen.find('[repeattype]')`

Если необходимо находить элементы с классом `choosen` **и** атрибутом `repeattype` необходимо указывать их в селекторе без пробела `.choosen[repeattype]`. Если необходимо находить элементы с классом `choosen` **или** элементы атрибутом `repeattype`, то необходимо ставить запятую `.choosen, [repeattype]`

См. также:

- [Знаете ли вы селекторы?](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors)
- [Multiple Class / ID and Class Selectors](https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/) (на английском)

Comment: А правильный ответ?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Какой вы быстрый. :) добавил

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, хреново я искал...